# R repeating a function

Tags: r

I have a list with not limited count: `parameter<-2,1,3,4,5......`
And I would like to repeat a function with the parameter:

```
 MyFunction('2')

 MyFunction('1')

 MyFunction('3')  etc.
```

Thank you very much for any tips

Comment: Have a look at `lapply`, something like: `lapply(parameter, MyFunction)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most things in R, there's more than one way of handling this problem. The `tidyverse` solution is first, followed by base R.

## purrr/map

I don't have detail about your desired output, but the `map` function from the `purrr` package will work in the situation you describe. Let's use the function `plus_one()` to demonstrate.

```
library(tidyverse) # Loads purrr and other useful functions

plus_one <- function(x) {x + 1} # Define our demo function

parameter <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

map(parameter, plus_one)
```

`map` returns a list, which isn't always desired. There are specialized versions of `map` for specific kinds of output. Depending on what you want to do, you `map_chr`, `map_int`, etc. In this case, we could use `map_dbl` to get a vector of the returned values.

```
map_dbl(parameter, plus_one)
```

## Base R

The `apply` family of functions from base R could also meet your needs. I prefer using `purrr` but some people like to stick with built-in functions.

```
lapply(parameter, plus_one)
sapply(parameter, plus_one)
```

You end up with the same results.

```
identical({map(parameter, plus_one)}, {lapply(parameter, plus_one)})
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: How would you do the same thing if `MyFuntion` took two arguments. One is the parameter one is the name of the df. Something like this? `MyFunction(dataframe,'2')`.