# Repeating a function for a series of values

Tags: r, function, loops

I have a question that is probably easy, but I am new to programming and I am struggling to understand how to do it. I basically need to run a user-written function for every value of a variable.

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld")
Grunfeld$quadri <- as.numeric(cut2(Grunfeld$year, g=4))

Grunfeld<-Grunfeld %>% select(-c(value,capital))
```

I have written a function that I have to apply to each one of the values in `quadri` that looks something like this

```
simil<- function(dataset,number){ # I create a function that calculates role equivalence

  sim_n <- dataset %>% filter(quadri==number) %>%select(-quadri) # the function is calculated for every year

  ### I need to spread the data before making correlation
  wide_n <- sim_n %>% spread (firm, inv)

  #To deal with NA, I follow the literature and consider those as 0s
  wide_n[is.na(wide_n)] <- 0
  cor_n <- as.data.frame(cor(wide_n[,(2:ncol(wide_n))]))

  # then i gather the data in long from
  sim_fin_n <- data.frame( # create a dataframe
    firm= rep(rownames(cor_n)[row(cor_n)]),
    `cmp_firm`= rep(colnames(cor_n)[col(cor_n)]),
    `sim_inv`=unlist(cor_n),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  rownames(sim_fin_n) <- NULL
  sim_fin_n<-sim_fin_n%>%filter(firm!=cmp_firm)
}
```

I would like to repeat my function for all the values in `quadri`. I could do this one by one, but it would be inefficient because in the real data I have hundred of values

```
# one by one
sim1<-simil(Grunfeld,1)%>% mutate(quadri=1)
sim2<-simil(Grunfeld,2)%>% mutate(quadri=2)
sim3<-simil(Grunfeld,3)%>% mutate(quadri=3)
sim4<-simil(Grunfeld,4)%>% mutate(quadri=4)
```

I would like to run the function for every value in `quadri` perhaps I need a for loop or the apply function, but I am struggling to understand how.

I have looked around and this question is similar, [R repeating a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333820/r-repeating-a-function) but I am unable to apply the answer to my case

Thank you very much in advance for your help

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution is using the purrr-package.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(purrr)
library(plm)

simil<- function(dataset,number){ 

  sim_n <- dataset %>% 
             filter(quadri==number) %>%
             select(-quadri) 

  wide_n <- sim_n %>% spread (firm, inv)

  wide_n[is.na(wide_n)] <- 0
  cor_n <- as.data.frame(cor(wide_n[,(2:ncol(wide_n))]))

  sim_fin_n <- data.frame( 
       firm= rep(rownames(cor_n)[row(cor_n)]),
       `cmp_firm`= rep(colnames(cor_n)[col(cor_n)]),
       `sim_inv`=unlist(cor_n),
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
       rownames(sim_fin_n) <- NULL

  sim_fin_n<-sim_fin_n %>% 
               filter(firm!=cmp_firm) %>%
               mutate(quadri = number) # Add to function!
```

}

Then you can use map_dfr() to apply the function multiple times, and row bind the results together into a data.frame:

```
purrr::map_dfr(1:4, ~simil(Grunfeld, .))
```

Edit:

Alternative way using lapply:

```
x <- lapply(1:4, function(x) simil(Grunfeld, x))
do.call(rbind, x)
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution! do you know if there is also a way to do it with lapply?